# Sms not sent with google smtp

Tags: smtp

my code

```
import smtplib
carriers = {
        'att':    '@mms.att.net',
        'tmobile':' @tmomail.net',
        'verizon':  '@vtext.com',
        'sprint':   '@page.nextel.com'
    }

def send(message):
        # Replace the number with your own, or consider using an argument\dict for multiple people.
    to_number = '0000{}'.format(carriers['att'])
    auth = ('mymail@gmail.com', 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx')#this is a app password

    # Establish a secure session with gmail's outgoing SMTP server using your gmail account
    
    server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )
    server.starttls()
    server.login(auth[0], auth[1])

    # Send text message through SMS gateway of destination number
    server.sendmail( auth[0], to_number, message)

omessage="Hi this is test."
send(omessage)
```

**bold**
Code runs successfully with no errors but sms not received
whats my mistake im a newbie to python and want to send sms not using api